# Getting results from logger to return to web app

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am very close, however not there yet. The logger displays the search results- however I still am not able to get the results to display on the web app.

The search on the web app does work and the results display in the logger.

Please advise. Thanks!

Here is updated,

Code:

```js
function SearchFiles(searchTerm) {
var searchFor ="title contains '" + searchTerm + "'";
var owneris ="and 'Email@email.com' in Owners";
 var names =[];
var fileIds=[];
  Logger.log(searchFor + " " + owneris);
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor + " " + owneris);
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  var fileId = file.getId();// To get FileId of the file
  fileIds.push(fileId);
  var name = file.getName();
  names.push(name);
}

for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
  //this is showing in the Logger
Logger.log(names[i]);
Logger.log("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + fileIds[i]);
}

}

function returnNames() {
  var names = SearchFiles();
   return '<b>returnNames has ran.!</b> <br>' + names ;

}

function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Hello World')
   //   .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}


function processForm(searchTerm) {
  var resultToReturn;
  Logger.log('processForm was called! ' + searchTerm);
  resultToReturn  = SearchFiles(searchTerm);
  Logger.log('resultToReturn: ' + resultToReturn)
  // shows as undefined in the logger
  return resultToReturn;
}

function helloWorld()
{
  return "Hello World!";
}
```

INDEX:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function displayMessage() {
        var searchTerm;
        searchTerm = document.getElementById('idSrchTerm').value;

        console.log('searchTerm: ' + searchTerm );
        
         google.script.run.processForm(searchTerm);
         google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(handleResults).returnNames();
       }
         
        
      function handleResults(returnVal){

         console.log('Handle Results was called! ');
         document.writeln(returnVal);
       }


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="idSrchTerm" name="search">   
    <input type="button" value="submitButton" name="submitButton" onclick="displayMessage()"/>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `withSuccessHandler` of the script runner. 
Check out the docs at:

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)

example:

```
  <script>
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(handleResults)    
    .processForm(searchTerm);

    function handleResults(returnVal){
      console.log(returnVal)
    }
   </script>
```

Comment: Thanks Spencer, I tried some of this but am still not able to get the results to display.  How can I get the following to display when I press submit? for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
  //this info is showing in the Logger. I want it to display on the website after pressing submit
Logger.log(names[i]);
Logger.log("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + fileIds[i]);
}

Comment: Your script  can return an array. just return `names`.

Comment: it says names is not defined when I add it within the handle results function on the index.html page

Comment: I have updated the above code, trying multiple ways I have still yet to get any results... Any help is appreciated.